# [Passport-Local]Authenticate OK but callback fails - req.user is empty

Tags: node.js, reactjs, session, request, passport-local

I have an app with working OAuth passport-google strategy implementation. 
I have issues to properly implement a passport-local strategy implementation.

I have tried to debug adding logs, what I see is that I go to the point where user is found in the Database and the done method is called.

At that point I get the following error :

```
_passport_Local-login
[0] all good { _id: 598d927ca4287c9102fd5339,
[0]   __v: 0,
[0]   local: 
[0]    { password: 
'$2a$08$r8B93TxFD0TLynw7jOAIXeFUR6OLWGDxQSiSmE62f0CRN1F3wE4ie',
[0]      email: 'yassinej@gmail.com' },
[0]   isAdmin: false }
[0] _authRoutes_req is: null
[0] events.js:182
[0]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[0]       ^
[0] 
[0] TypeError: res.redirect is not a function
[0]     at app.post.passport.authenticate 
 (/Users/dev/workspace/React/Projects/oerk_v3/server/routes/authRoutes.js:9:8)
[0]     at Strategy.strategy.success (/Users/dev/workspace/React/Projects/oerk_v3/server/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:201:18)
[0]     at verified (/Users/dev/workspace/React/Projects/oerk_v3/server/node_modules/passport-local/lib/strategy.js:83:10)
[0]     at /Users/dev/workspace/React/Projects/oerk_v3/server/services/passport.js:68:15
[0]     at model.Query.<anonymous> (/Users/dev/workspace/React/Projects/oerk_v3/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3822:16)
[0]     at /Users/dev/workspace/React/Projects/oerk_v3/server/node_modules/kareem/index.js:273:21
[0]     at /Users/dev/workspace/React/Projects/oerk_v3/server/node_modules/kareem/index.js:131:16
[0]     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:95:7)
[0]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9)
[1] Proxy error: Could not proxy request /auth/login from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000.
[1] See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNRESET).
```

I can't figure out the issue since I am following same process as for the google strategy which works fine.

You can find my code here:

Server Side:
- Index.js is at root
- Routes:
   https://github.com/yassinej/oerkv3/blob/master/routes/authRoutes.js

- Passport:
  https://github.com/yassinej/oerkv3/blob/master/services/passport.js

Any advise is welcome.
Cheers.
Yassine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the where the pb is. 
 'res' can't redirect because it is my user object.

I must have mixed up something with my action/reducer.
I don't have a fix but i'll work on it. Now that I Know.

Any suggestion is welcome.
Cheers.

Comment: Look here: http://passportjs.org/docs#custom-callback (it also explains why the second argument is your user object)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I had previously read it probably too fast. I removed the custom callback and user the default redirect: `passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
   failureRedirect: '/login',
   successRedirect: '/'
  })`